# SQL update statement to change the value of a field and not replace it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in the process of migrating some databases. I have this table that has a couple of hundred rows, and has a filename column. To each record in this table, the filename column needs to be altered and part of a path needs to be prepended to the value that is in that field.

The table is like:

```
| 1 | filename1 |
| 2 | filename2 |
```

and needs to become:

```
| 1 | path/filename1 |
| 2 | path/filename2 |
```

I am not an SQL guru, but I know the basics. This eludes me though. Is there a way to do something like:

```
update table 
   set filename = 'path/' + filename 
 where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You pretty much have it right there. You don't need to specify a `where` clause if you want to do it for all the rows, so then it would just be:

```
update table set filename = 'path/' || filename;
```

(`||` is the concatenation operator in PostgreSQL)

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator in PLSQL, which is used by Oracle and another db that escapes me ATM.

Comment: Also figures in the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

They have told you how to write teh concatenation, I suggest you run this selct first to see waht your results will be:

```
select filename, 'path/'|| filename  from table
where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
UPDATE table SET filename = CONCAT("path/", filename);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE  table
SET     filename = 'path/' || filename
WHERE   id = 1
```